# Append() Ajax not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load my menu navigation from database. I have this HTML:

```html
<ul id="nav-mobile"></ul>
```

Now I want to append data on success of ajax request into `id="nav-mobile"`
I am using this code:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"/findRubriques", 
  type: "GET",
  success: function(rubriques) {
    $.each(rubriques, function(i, rubrique) {
      $('#nav-mobile').append("<li><a href='categorie.html?rubriqueId=" + rubrique.id + ">" + rubrique.libelle + "</a></li>");            
    });
  }
})
```

The problem is  when I load my page, the menu is displayed correctly and other times the menu is not displayed. However in both cases when I check my logs in the browser, my ajax request code ajax is 200

Comment: Are you running the AJAX request within a document.ready event handler? It sounds like you have a race condition happening if it's intermittently failing

Comment: So sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't?  When it "doesn't work", how specifically does it fail?  What is the content of `rubriques` when this happens?  Does `$('#nav-mobile')` find anything when this happens?  Debug.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to pass to `$.each`? A json string? If yes, you should add `dataType` to your ajax configs, to specify how to parse the response. Else, you can parse manually `rubriques` using `JSON.parse()`.
Add an "error" callback too, so you can print the error if ajax can't parse your response.